# Why does the sequence $a_n=\sin\frac{n\pi }{2n+7}$ converge to $1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence:

$$a_n=\sin\frac{n\pi}{2n+7}.$$

If we take the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ of the sequence, why does it converge to $1$?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\frac{n\pi}{2n+7} = 1.$$

Comment: Hint: continuity

Comment: What would it converge to, had sinus not been there?

Answer (score 3):

Recall the following:

- $\sin(x)$ is continuous everywhere and hence $\displaystyle \lim_{x_n \to a} \sin(x_n) = \sin(a)$.
- Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n}{2n+7} = \dfrac12$
- $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}2 \right) = 1$